# Что мы получаем при разыменовывании указателя на функцию?

Tags: c++, c

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
 return a + b;
}
int main()
{ 
 unsigned long long a = (unsigned long long)sum;
 cout << ((int(*)(int, int))a)(3, 4) ;  
 cout << (*(int(*)(int, int))a)(3, 4) ;//почему это аналогично верхнему?
}
```

Почему эти 2 cout-A одинаковые по поведению?И что дает этот указатель во втором случае?

Вот еще,по моему аналогичный пример:

```
void message()
{
 std::cout << "Hello, World" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
 void (*mg)();
 mg=message;

 message();    
 (*message)(); //Для чего писать такое разыменовывание,и что при этом происходит?

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: В обоих случаях касты и разыменования совершенно бесполезны и являются noop

Answer (score 3):

При разыменовывании указателя на функцию мы получаем lvalue, ссылающееся на эту функцию. Если применить оператор вызова функции к такому значению, то эта функция и будет вызвана.  [[expr.unary.op]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1) :

> The unary *** operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. [...]

Чтобы вызвать функцию, оператор вызова функции также можно применить непосредственно к указателю на функцию, без предварительного разыменовывания указателя.  [[expr.call]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#1) :

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function. [...] The postfix expression shall have function type or **function pointer type**. [...]

---

Чтобы присвоить указателю на функцию адрес функции, вы можете воспользоваться оператором `&`:

```
void message() {...}
...
void (*mg)() = &message;
```

Впрочем, использовать оператор `&` совсем не обязательно, так как существует неявное преобразование функции в указатель на функцию  [[conv.func]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.func#1) :

> An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`”.
> The result is a pointer to the function.

Вот почему можно написать так:

```
void (*mg)() = message;
```

---

Напоследок замечу, что преобразование указателя на функцию в целочисленный тип — это условно-поддерживаемя конструкция. Стандарт языка не требует, чтобы такой код:

```
unsigned long long a = (unsigned long long)sum;
```

успешно компилировался.  [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8) :

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. [...]

Comment: [Интересный баг](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47013385/13970074) в тему